# row inside a cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following simple code that generates the location of various records in a table.

```
 return (
        <TableRow>

            <TableCell >
                // some code_1
            </TableCell>
                
            <TableCell >
                // some code_2
            </TableCell>

            <TableCell>
                <TableRow>  // here I get warning
                    <TableCell>
                        // some code_3
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell >
                        // some code_4
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell >
                        // some code_5
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableCell>
               
            <TableCell 
                // some code_6
            </TableCell>

        </TableRow >
    );
```

And as you can guess, when I add more components to the TableCell (in my case I add TableRow ), I get a warning:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): tr cannot appear as a child of td.

Tell me how to save this table structure, get rid of warnings

Comment: I hate to be obvious, here, but `TableRow` is going to render as `<tr>` and `TableCell` is going to render as `<td>`. So...if you want the error to go away, don't put rows inside of cells.

Comment: You can put table rows inside your cells but not directly. They need to be wrapped in their own seperate inner table element. In the rendered html it will look something like ... > td > table > tbody > tr > td > ...

Comment: @samuei Thank you for the answer. Well if I can't put a TableRow inside a TableCell without warnings popping up. But I need to save this table structure. How can i do this?

Comment: @schwaber Thanks for the advice. Could you show how to do it with a code example?

Comment: What does it mean _to you_ for a `TableCell` to contain a `TableRow`?  A table is a set of rows, each row is a set of columns.  There aren't more rows inside each column unless you nest an entirely new table in that cell.

Comment: @Wyck TableCell is a cell that contains three rows. All other TableCells contain one row each and there are no problems. But here I need to fit three lines into one cell, and without a warning I can’t do this

Comment: @Paul.  Unfortunately, with HTML, cells do not contain rows.  If you want a cell to contain rows you have two options. 1) embed another table in that cell and add three rows to it (and presumably only one column).  2)  Make all the other columns of that row have a [_rowspan_](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp), this is awkward, but basically you design your table with the maximal rows and columns necessary and "merge" cells together as necessary. (this is how you'd set it up in Excel - every cell has a unique row/col index requiring _spanning_ but not requiring _nesting_.

Comment: @Paul I have edited your code in my answer below to wrap the rows accordingly, but I have not tested if it works. Please mark it as accepted answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my comment above:

You can put table rows inside your cells but not directly. They need to be wrapped in their own seperate inner table element. In the rendered html it will look something like ... > td > table > tbody > tr > td > ...

In this examble I have wrapped your table rows in tables with table body elements, but you may want to wrap the top row in a table head element, `<TableHead>` instead and subsequently the rest in a table body.

Table head and body may not be required so you can try to place the rows directly inside the table element.

Here is the documentation from Material UI https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/

```
return (
    <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
            // some code_1
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
            // some code_2
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
            <Table>
            <TableBody>  
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>
                        // some code_3
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>
                        // some code_4
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>
                        // some code_5
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableCell>   
        <TableCell> 
            // some code_6
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
);
```